# boto3 upload_file() 403 forbidden with Wasabi S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, pre-signed-url, wasabi

I've worked through all the threads concerning this problem but haven't found anything.

Whenever I try to download a file from Wasabi S3, I get a 403 forbidden error. The file is uploaded with a pre-signed url that was signed with the same access key as the one I am using for the download request.

For the signed url I tried setting the ACL to "private" as well as "public-read". But that hasn't changed anything. I did also experiment with different access keys with different permissions for signing and downloading. But also no change.

Any more suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, the endpoint_url parameter is not optional when initializing boto3.client.

Comment: Yes, thanks for catching the mistake. I edited it.